# Plupload for amazon s3 with asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, plupload

My plupload code is working fine . I need to save file name and file size to table after uploading successfully . How can i do that in asp.net with c# , I have searched a lot but i didnt find anything help full.

my working code is here

```
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="images/upload_images.png" style="width: 960px" />
</div>
<div id="runtimediv">No runtime found.</div>
<div id="uploaderdiv">
<p>Your browser does not have HTML5, Flash, or Silverlight support.</p></div>
```

java script

```
// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(function () {
    $("#uploaderdiv").plupload({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4,gears,browserplus',
        url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<%=BucketName%>',
        max_file_size: '5000mb',

        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': '<%=foldername%>/${filename}', // use filename as a key
            'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
            'acl': 'public-read',
            //'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId': '<%=AWSAccessKeyID%>',
            'policy': '<%=PolicyDocument%>',
            'signature': '<%=PolicyDocumentSignature%>'
        },

        preinit: {
            Init: function (up, params) {
                $('#runtimediv').html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
            }
        },

        // !!!Important!!! 
        // this is not recommended with S3, since it will force Flash runtime into the mode, with no progress indication
        //resize : {width : 800, height : 600, quality : 60},  // Resize images on clientside, if possible 

        // optional, but better be specified directly
        file_data_name: 'file',

        // re-use widget (not related to S3, but to Plupload UI Widget)
        multiple_queues: true,

        // Specify what files to browse for
        //filters : [
        //  {title : "JPEG files", extensions : "jpg"}
        //],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/plupload_v1.5.4/js/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload_v1.5.4/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });
});
```

C# Code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();



                if (Session["username"] == crs.username && crs.username != null && crs.username != "")
                {
                    AWSAccessKeyID = crs.AWSAccessKey;        //** put your value here **
                    AWSSecretAccessKey = crs.AWSSecretKey;    //** put your value here **
                    BucketName = crs.BUCKET_NAME;            //** put your value here **

                    //  crs.foldname = "user130";
                    foldername = crs.foldname;


                    DateTime ExpirationDate;
                    ExpirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);

                    PolicyDocument = "";
                    PolicyDocument += "{";
                    PolicyDocument += "  \"expiration\": \"" + ExpirationDate.ToString("s") + ".000Z\",";
                    PolicyDocument += "  \"conditions\": [";
                    PolicyDocument += "    {\"bucket\": \"" + BucketName + "\"},";
                    PolicyDocument += "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},";
                    PolicyDocument += "    {\"success_action_status\": \"201\"},";
                    //PolicyDocument += "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],";
                    PolicyDocument += "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Filename\", \"\"],";
                    PolicyDocument += "    [\"starts-with\", \"$name\", \"\"],";
                    PolicyDocument += "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"],";
                    PolicyDocument += "  ]";
                    PolicyDocument += "}";

                    Byte[] ByteArray;
                    ByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PolicyDocument);
                    Response.Write(ByteArray);
                    PolicyDocument = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray);

                    ByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AWSSecretAccessKey);

                    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 MyHMACSHA1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(ByteArray);

                    ByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PolicyDocument);

                    Byte[] HashArray;
                    HashArray = MyHMACSHA1.ComputeHash(ByteArray);

                    PolicyDocumentSignature = System.Convert.ToBase64String(HashArray);

                    BindGridview();

                    //Uncomment the following lines if you would like to check if a CORS configuration exists and apply 
                    //one if it does not exist.

                    if (GetBucketCorsExists() == false)
                    {
                        SetBucketCors();
                    }

                    /*    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                        table.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(decimal));

                        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                           System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                            row["ID"] = i;
                            row["Name"] = "Name " + i;
                            row["Salary"] = 10000 * i;
                            table.Rows.Add(row);
                        }

                        GridView1.DataSource = table;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

                        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                        } 

                    */
                }
                else
                { Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); }

            }
        }




        private static Boolean GetBucketCorsExists()
        {
            String RequestURL;
            String RequestMethod;
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> ExtraRequestHeaders;
            String AuthorizationValue;
            SprightlySoftAWS.REST MyREST = new SprightlySoftAWS.REST();
            Boolean RetBool;
            String PostData;

            int ErrorNumber = 0;
            String ErrorDescription = "";
            String LogData = "";
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullRequestHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
            int ResponseStatusCode = 0;
            String ResponseStatusDescription = "";
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullResponseHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
            String ResponseString = "";

            RequestURL = MyREST.BuildS3RequestURL(true, "s3.amazonaws.com", BucketName, "", "?cors");
            RequestMethod = "GET";
            PostData = "";

            ExtraRequestHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
            ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r"));

            AuthorizationValue = MyREST.GetS3AuthorizationValue(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, AWSAccessKeyID, AWSSecretAccessKey);
            ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationValue);

            RetBool = MakeAWSRequest(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, PostData, ref ErrorNumber, ref ErrorDescription, ref LogData, ref FullRequestHeaders, ref ResponseStatusCode, ref ResponseStatusDescription, ref FullResponseHeaders, ref ResponseString);

            if (ResponseStatusCode == 404)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (RetBool == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(LogData);
            }
        }

        private static void SetBucketCors()
        {
            String RequestURL;
            String RequestMethod;
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> ExtraRequestHeaders;
            String AuthorizationValue;
            SprightlySoftAWS.REST MyREST = new SprightlySoftAWS.REST();
            Boolean RetBool;
            String PostData;

            int ErrorNumber = 0;
            String ErrorDescription = "";
            String LogData = "";
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullRequestHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
            int ResponseStatusCode = 0;
            String ResponseStatusDescription = "";
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullResponseHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
            String ResponseString = "";

            PostData = "";
            PostData += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
            PostData += "<CORSConfiguration xmlns=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/\">";
            PostData += "<CORSRule>";
            PostData += "<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>";
            PostData += "<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>";
            PostData += "<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>";
            PostData += "<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>";
            PostData += "<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>";
            PostData += "<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>";
            PostData += "<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>";
            PostData += "</CORSRule>";
            PostData += "</CORSConfiguration>";

            RequestURL = MyREST.BuildS3RequestURL(true, "s3.amazonaws.com", BucketName, "", "?cors");
            RequestMethod = "PUT";

            ExtraRequestHeaders = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();

            SprightlySoftAWS.S3.CalculateHash MyCalculateHash = new SprightlySoftAWS.S3.CalculateHash();
            String MyMD5;
            MyMD5 = MyCalculateHash.CalculateMD5FromString(PostData);
            ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("Content-MD5", MyMD5);

            ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r"));

            AuthorizationValue = MyREST.GetS3AuthorizationValue(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, AWSAccessKeyID, AWSSecretAccessKey);
            ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationValue);

            RetBool = MakeAWSRequest(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, PostData, ref ErrorNumber, ref ErrorDescription, ref LogData, ref FullRequestHeaders, ref ResponseStatusCode, ref ResponseStatusDescription, ref FullResponseHeaders, ref ResponseString);

            if (RetBool == false)
            {
                throw new Exception(LogData);
            }
        }

        private static Boolean MakeAWSRequest(String RequestURL, String RequestMethod, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> UserRequestHeaders, String PostData, ref int ErrorNumber, ref String ErrorDescription, ref String LogData, ref System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullRequestHeaders, ref int ResponseStatusCode, ref String ResponseStatusDescription, ref System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String> FullResponseHeaders, ref String ResponseStringFormatted)
        {
            SprightlySoftAWS.REST MyREST = new SprightlySoftAWS.REST();
            Boolean RetBool = true;
            LogData = "";
            int AWSErrorRetries = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i <= AWSErrorRetries; i++)
            {
                LogData += Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-Request Started " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-RequestURL=" + RequestURL + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-RequestMethod=" + RequestMethod + Environment.NewLine;

                if (UserRequestHeaders != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<String, String> MyKeyValuePair in UserRequestHeaders)
                    {
                        LogData += "-RequestHeader=" + MyKeyValuePair.Key + ":" + MyKeyValuePair.Value + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                LogData += "-RequestPostData=" + PostData + Environment.NewLine;

                RetBool = MyREST.MakeRequest(RequestURL, RequestMethod, UserRequestHeaders, PostData);

                LogData += "-Request Complete " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-ResponseErrorNumber=" + MyREST.ErrorNumber + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-ResponseErrorDescription=" + MyREST.ErrorDescription + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-ResponseStatusCode=" + MyREST.ResponseStatusCode + Environment.NewLine;
                LogData += "-ResponseStatusDescription=" + MyREST.ResponseStatusDescription + Environment.NewLine;

                if (MyREST.ResponseHeaders != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<String, String> MyKeyValuePair in MyREST.ResponseHeaders)
                    {
                        LogData += "-ResponseHeader=" + MyKeyValuePair.Key + ":" + MyKeyValuePair.Value + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }

                LogData += "-ResponseString=" + MyREST.ResponseString + Environment.NewLine;

                //Set the return values.
                ErrorNumber = MyREST.ErrorNumber;
                ErrorDescription = MyREST.ErrorDescription;
                FullRequestHeaders = MyREST.RequestHeaders;
                ResponseStatusCode = MyREST.ResponseStatusCode;
                ResponseStatusDescription = MyREST.ResponseStatusDescription;
                FullResponseHeaders = MyREST.ResponseHeaders;
                ResponseStringFormatted = MyREST.ResponseStringFormatted;

                if (RetBool == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MyREST.ResponseStatusCode == 500 || MyREST.ResponseStatusCode == 503)
                    {
                        //A Service Unavailable response was returned.  Wait and retry.
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * i * i);
                    }
                    else if (MyREST.ResponseStatusCode == 0 && MyREST.ErrorNumber == 1003)
                    {
                        //Getting the response failed.  This may be a network disconnection.  Wait and retry.
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * i * i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //An error occured but retrying would not solve the problem.
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RetBool;
        }
```

Comment: you are mentioning `url` as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/<%=BucketName%>`, doesnt that mean it will be trying to upload to the amazon s3 directly? and because of that it the execution wouldn't be reaching inside your `IsPostBack` code in your code behind?

Comment: I guess you need to add a handler to plupload FileUploaded event. This handler will retrieve the file name and size from the returned json data (or uploader) and perform an ajax call to your asp.net application with this data.

Comment: Thanks jbl, I try your suggestion.

Comment: Vijay , This code is working perfectly. there is no issue, i just need to track files and file sizes.

Comment: I am not able to make workable handler for plupload for amazon s3. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do something similar; Here is what I have done;

You can use the FileUploaded plupload event:

```
   FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
            // Called when a file has finished uploading
            log('[FileUploaded] File:', file, "Info:", info);
                            // Call a webmethod to store in DB
        },
```

In the FileUploaded event you can call a **webmethod** (with it send the file name and size); the webmethod would save the information to the DB

Hope this helps